# How to add the string first and last to the checkbox by jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

**This is my html:**

```
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Red">Red</input>
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Green">Green</input>
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Blue">Blue</input>
<input class="eret" type="button" value="Get checkboxes" id="getCheckboxesButton"></input>
<div id="debugOutput">
</div>
```

**This is my javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getCheckboxesButton').live('click', function(event) {
        var checkboxValues = [];
        $('input.eret[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index, elem) {
            checkboxValues.push($(elem).val());
        });
        $('#debugOutput').html(checkboxValues.join(','));
    });
});
```

How can I define Javascript code with this output?

**Output (Example):**

```
Color:"Green"  --> One : Without Comma

Color:"Green",Color:"Blue" / Color:"Red",Color:"Green",Color:"Blue"  --> Multi : With Comma
```

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/behrouzbash/z903jrf4/3/)

Comment: You're using `Live()` instead of `on()` as a handler, `live()` is removed from the jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getCheckboxesButton').on('click', function(event) {
        var checkboxValues = [];
        $('input.eret[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index, elem) {
            checkboxValues.push('Color:"'  +  $(elem).val() + '"');
        });
        $('#debugOutput').html(checkboxValues.join(','));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Red">Red
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Green">Green
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Blue">Blue
<input class="eret" type="button" value="Get checkboxes" id="getCheckboxesButton">
<div id="debugOutput">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `this` keyword to access the selected value:

what you were doing is instead of using `on` click event you used `live()` and [Live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) has been removed and should be replaced with `on(...)`.

> Live() API has been removed in jQuery 1.9; please use on() instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#getCheckboxesButton').on('click', function(event) {
          var checkboxValues = [];
          $('input.eret[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index, elem) {
               checkboxValues.push('Color:"' + $(this).val() + '"');
          });
          $('#debugOutput').html(checkboxValues.join(','));
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Red">Red</input>
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Green">Green</input>
<input class="eret" type="checkbox" value="Blue">Blue</input>
<input class="eret" type="button" value="Get checkboxes" id="getCheckboxesButton"></input>
<div id="debugOutput">
</div>
```